# How show specific content inside iframe on another site using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I need to target a specific area on another site and have that module fit to the size of the iframe. I would figure jQuery might be used best targeting a div id or class that the content I need is wrapped around it. Any ideas?

Comment: So the iframe is on the other site? But you want to display it on your site?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#id', window.frames['frame-name'].document)
```